# Upgrading to Three js 0.130.1 version Points rendered with shadermaterial and buffergeometry not rendering

Tags: three.js

We were using Three 0.115 version and everything was working. Since we got vulnerability issues for < 0.125, we decided to upgrade to latest version. Then we are getting issues with shader material.

We have an application that uses Point cloud rendered with buffer geometry(positions, sizes and colors bufferattributes) and shadermaterial.

```
function vertexShader() {
  return `attribute float size;
  attribute vec3 customColor;
  varying vec3 vColor;
  attribute float visibility;
  varying float vVisible;
  void main() {
    vColor = customColor;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    vVisible = visibility;
  }`
}

function fragmentShader() {
  return `uniform vec3 color;
  uniform sampler2D pointTexture;
  varying vec3 vColor;
  varying float vVisible;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4( color * vColor, 1.0 );
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( pointTexture, gl_PointCoord );
    if ( gl_FragColor.a < ALPHATEST ) discard;
    if (vVisible < 0.5) discard;
  }`
}
```

and in our javascript init code.

```
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      color: { value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
      texture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(circle) },
      resolution: { value: new THREE.Vector2() },
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader(),
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader(),
    alphaTest: 0.9,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
  });
```

there is no error in console. But points are not rendered.
we use raycast for detecting points and that works without any issue.

Any idea why after upgrading to latest version of three, rendering of points fails?
is this something to do with shadermaterial?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395434/threejs-latest-version-0-130-1-is-not-rendering-shadermaterial?

Comment: Can you simplify your code to reduce the noise? You might also find the issue this way.

Comment: @Mugen87 _Technically_ the other is the duplicate. :) Otherwise, yes, word-for-word.